# AppCrash in mscorlib.dll: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.ManualResetEvent' to type 'System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback'

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

My application randomly crashes on my target machines with an .net failure. In *mscorelib.dll* there seems to be a *System.InvalidCastException*.
The error occures in:

```
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
```

and the reason is:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.ManualResetEvent' to type 'System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback'.`
```

The Application runs multiple times on the target machine (win7 x64).
The Application is a x86 application.

There have never been issues before I was forced to compile the Application to the .net 4.6+ target framework. But I need to go up to at least 4.6 due to other dependencies now.

I thought it could be a issue with garbage collection and set `<gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>`. But this did not help.

I tried to debug the miniDumps with WinDbg. But I was not successful to find a way to track the Issue down to a specific line of code or a method in my code. I don't think it is a .net issue, but I have no clue how to find the corresponding line in my code.

Edit on request:

- Former .net target framework: 4.5.1
- The application crashes randomly, could be after more than 24h
- I'm not able to figure out in which part of my code the application crashes
- The same application runs independent parallel on the same machine. Sometimes randomly one or two instances crash.

Comment: Can you show the code, where the exception is raised.

Comment: What was the old Net Version?  So it is failing randomly?   You said "runs multiple times".  What does that mean?

Comment: @FrankNielsen Unfortunately I can't show the code, because I don't have a clue at which part of the Project the exception is raised. I just get pointed to mscorlib.dll. Do you have an Idea how to find the corresponding part of my code?

Comment: @jdweng It run well compiled to .net 4.5.1. Exactly, it is failing randomly. Could happen after more than 24h. The same application runs parallel on the same machine a view times. (Independent Instances). Randomly on or two of them crash.

Comment: So you can not produce a stacktrace/see callstack? Does it fail when debugging?

Comment: These type problems are difficult to find.  I usually do two things 1) Create a log file and put messages when you enter and leave sections of code to attempt to isolate issue.  2) Add more exception handlers.  Usually these type problems are due to an exception occurring.  When you do not have an exception handler in a section of code the compiled code move up[ the execution stack until the first exception is found in a ancestor module.  So the error being reported may be confusing or wrong.

Comment: @FrankNielsen The 'stacktrace' given by .net does not point to my code just to the mscorlib.dll. I never have seen it failing in debugging. But my Dev-System is Win10. The targets are still Win7.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for that Information. I cant do that with some kind of "global exception handler", right?

Comment: What kind of application is it - Console, WPF or ?

Comment: No because it may find an exception handler before a Global one.  I suspect the fix is going to be adding a lock.  I think two parallel processes are entering the same code and having a conflict.  The WaitHandler  Will not prevent this issue.  I had similar issue with a FIFO.  Two parallel events were trying to read and write FIFO.  So I wrote a method Read_Write(Boolean Write).  And then added a lock in method so only one read or one write could occur at any one time.  The write set Write True and the Read set Write false.

Comment: @FrankNielsen it is a WindowsForms application.

Comment: Do you have any `Task.Run()`, 'Parallel.x` or any threading in your application?